# google maps api v3 - open infowindow from an external click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So i have a V3 map which is initialised like this:

```
function init() {
        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5081289,-0.128005);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          'zoom': 6,
          'center': mapCenter,
          'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
          panControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          zoomControl: true,
          zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
            },
        });
```

and a load of markers that look like this:

```
var marker25837500 = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              pop_title: 'blah blah',                                                                                                 
              pop_wind: 'more blah',
                      zIndex: 999,
              icon: 'images/map_icons/s6.png'
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker25837500, 'click', onMarkerClick);
```

and lastly i have a function to open the infowindow on he click of each maker:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var onMarkerClick = OpenInfoWindow;

function OpenInfoWindow() {
          var marker = this;
          infoWindow.setContent('<h3>' + marker.pop_title + '</h3>' +
                                         marker.pop_body);

          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        };
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
          infoWindow.close();
        });
```

My question is, what do i need to do to make a particular marker (say marker25837500) show its infowindow when a  inside the page is clicked - perhaps something like:

```
<div id="marker25837500">click to see infoWindow!</div>
```

I'm sure it's easy but i just can see my way though it!

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might use `trigger` event.

```
$('#marker25837500').click(function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker25837500, 'click')
})
```

Check this- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

**Edit:** Also noticed that you are calling `onMarkerClick()` when `marker25837500` is clicked, but you named the other function `OpenInfoWindow()` so you might need to change that too.

Comment: hmm - been playing with it, and it doesnt seem to like it. Added:
$('#marker25837500').click(function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker25837500, 'click');
   alert("hello"); 
  });
And also added a div with the correct id. The alert pops up, but nothing happens on the map... any pointers?

Comment: Can you `alert(marker25837500)` in this function and check if the `marker25837500` -the marker variable itself is in scope?

Comment: yes - the alert gives me [object HTMLDivElement] - so that looks ok. Also, i missed a couple of lines above the OpenInfoWindow which i have now added in... thanks

Comment: Hmm. The alert should have showed a marker object -referring to your code `var marker25837500 = new google.maps.Marker({...` So something else is wrong.

Comment: could it be confusing the div for the marker (the id is the same as the marker name). changing the marker name makes the function stop working... so it looks like it's unable to get a handle on marker25837500

Comment: yeah - Uncaught ReferenceError: marker25837500x is not defined - am i not declaring it right? thanks...

Comment: Yeah something like that. If I were doing this, I'd keep the markers in an (globally available) array, and set up the `<div>`s with `id="infoWindow_{markerarray_index}"`.

Comment: What if I have all the infowindow in a an array?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything unusual or simulate a `click` on the marker; just make sure the `OpenInfoWindow` function can be reached:

```
//This is the simple case:
var myDiv = document.getElementById( "marker25837500" );
google.maps.event.addDomListener( myDiv, "click", OpenInfoWindow );

//Or if you have other things that you want to accomplish when this occurs:
var myDiv = document.getElementById( "marker25837500" );
google.maps.event.addDomListener( myDiv, "click", function() {
    OpenInfoWindow();
    //Do other stuff here
});
```

As long as the `InfoWindow` is in scope (can be reached when the `OpenInfoWindow` function is called), this should work fine.