# How to link a button to a google map marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create my own map using google map.

I want to create a list showing all existing markers on the map. When user clicks on one button/link from the list, the corresponding marker will be centered and its infoWindow will be displayed, i.e. the same effects as the user clicks on the marker.

I have tried a number of solutions, but I could get none of them working. Can anyone please offer me a simple solution for this? Thanks in advance!

My existing code is as follows,

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.642588,151.171875),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          mapTypeControl: false
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      var onMarkerClick1 = function() {
      var marker = this;     
      infoWindow.setContent('content of infowindow');
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  };
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(19.642588,151.171875),
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', onMarkerClick1);
```

Comment: You might take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798435/google-maps-api-v3-open-infowindow-from-an-external-click/10798479#10798479

Answer (score 1):

this won't center the map on it, but will move so the whole balloon is visible

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map2.htm

---

as simple as i can get it. yes, please use GMarker etc.

don't forget this in the header `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?`...

you'll need html that includes

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>
 <div id="side_bar"><a href="javascript:myclick(marker)">Marker One</a><br /></div>
```

and then javascript

```
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(19.642588, 151.171875), 8);

    var point = new GLatLng(19.642588, 151.171875);
    var marker = new GMarker(point);

    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml("this marker has been clicked");
    });

    function myclick(i) {
        GEvent.trigger(marker, "click");
    }

    map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: Thanks but I have seen this solution but could not understand it. Do i need to change all my markers from Marker to GMarker to get it work?

Comment: OP is using V3 but this answer is applicable to V2.