# Show and Hide info window on Google Map Icons V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a site i am working on and i would like to have the option where they can click on a rig name and then it will show the info window. The icons would be on show all the time but can be clicked on through the icon or side bar.

I have tried to solve this but i am having no luck.

Here is the test link with the code in source.http://excalibur.3peaksmedia.com/excalibur-rig-locator.asp

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

```
function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.705027, -110.470963),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var inventory = markers[i].getAttribute("inventory");
          var layout = markers[i].getAttribute("layout");
          var specs = markers[i].getAttribute("specs");
          var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<div class='balloon' style='width:190px; height:140px; font-family:Eau;'>" + "<b>" + name + "</b> <br>" + address + "<br>" + "> <a target=_blank href='/pdf/" + markers[i].getAttribute("inventory") + "'> Rig Inventory PDF</a> <br>" + "><a target=_blank href='/pdf/" + markers[i].getAttribute("layout") + "'> Rig Layout PDF</a> " + "<br>> <a target=_blank href='/pdf/" + markers[i].getAttribute("specs") + "'> Pump & Well Control Specs </a> <br>" + "> <a href='" + markers[i].getAttribute("friendlyurl") + "'>View Gallery</a>";
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include relevant part of the source code here. The link may break in the future and this question would lack important information. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in help.

Comment: I can't find the relevant code in your page where you add the links (which are not links btw.) in your sidebar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798435/google-maps-api-v3-open-infowindow-from-an-external-click

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps api … showing a markers infowindow from a link outside of the map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469322/google-maps-api-showing-a-markers-infowindow-from-a-link-outside-of-the-map)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `google.maps.event.trigger` to trigger a click event on a marker (which will cause the associated info-window to open). Example:

```
$("#sidebarLink1").click(function(){ 
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker1, 'click');
});
```

Comment: add the code after `bindInfoWindow`. `#sidebarLink1` needs to be the id of the sidebar link you want to open the info-window. Right now, your sidebar links are just `p` tags. You need to give them each a unique id, which you can use to bind the click event.

Comment: levi please can you help me with this? I am still struggling.

Comment: The basic idea is this: when you generate your sidebar, you want to give each sidebar link a unique id, which will be used to associate it with a marker on the map. When you create your map markers, for each marker, you will bind to the associated sidebar links click event, and use this to trigger the click event on the given marker, which will  cause the markers info-window to open.

Comment: I am struggling to understand how to put this together. I am new to this and have tried a few things from your suggestion but nothing seems to work. I listed my full code below as answer which was wrong. But it shows how i have the list of rigs setup. How would I indicate the onclick event for each rig and show the javascript?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: would you be able to give some example code based on my project?

Comment: I cannot do the work for you. Here is a the basic idea to get you started - http://pastebin.com/44Gebj52. If you have trouble, read up on "javascript loops", and "jquery click events". Between those two, you will figure this out.